# SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

Given a working example in T-SQL:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ) as row_id
 FROM 
[schemaName].[Zoo]
```

If I keep * selector it throws following error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

Is there a way to keep * selector, and make it work in oracle pl/sql? (currently I could achieve wanted result only by mentioning all column names)

Comment: What's this got to do with plsql? If nothing, please remove from tag list. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ) as row_id FROM schemaName.Zoo a
```

Here **a** is alias for table schemaName.Zoo. This will generate all columns from the original table, with row_id column added at the end.

Comment: perfect, it does the job! Thank you

Comment: Of course, with Oracle you'll need to get rid of the square braces.

Comment: problem was not in squares, it was in alias, Microsoft sql supported * without alias, Oracle as I see does not

Comment: @meta4: that's true, but with square braces in the query it won't execute in Oracle - or at least it won't execute in Oracle 11.1, which is what I happen to have handy for testing right now.

Comment: ohh yes I assumed to translate the query

Answer (score 3):

Use `SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER ... FROM tablename t;`